# Change background color of Google Doc with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I want to change the page color of my entire document using Google Apps Script. I do not want to change the highlight color of a paragraph. I want to do the equivalent of going to `File > Page Setup > Page color`.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I don't think there is any way to set the page background color in Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to change the background color of Google Document.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

I thought that in this case, there are 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, Document service (DocumentApp) is used. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Document and run the function `myFunction`. In this sample, the background of Document is set as the red color.

```
function myFunction() {
  const obj = {[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR]: "#ff0000"};
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().setAttributes(obj);
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Google Docs API is used. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Document, and [please enable Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, run the function `myFunction`. In this sample, the background of Document is set as the red color.

```
function myFunction() {
  const documentId = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  const resource = { requests: [{ updateDocumentStyle: { documentStyle: { background: { color: { color: { rgbColor: { red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0 } } } } }, fields: "background" } }] };
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(resource, documentId);
}
```

### Result:

When above 2 patterns are used, the following result is obtained.

#### From:

[image]

#### To:

[image]

### References:

- [setAttributes(attributes)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#setattributesattributes)
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateDocumentStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatedocumentstylerequest)